# JOOQ - query without quotes

Tags: oracle, jooq

I use JOOQ-3.1.0 to generate and execute dynamic queries for Oracle and Postgresql with Spring-4. In a scenario I have a partitioned table, which I need to query using JOOQ. I use `DSL.tableByName(vblTablename);` where `vblTablename` is the string received as a string in the query generation method, ex, `vbl_default partition(p_04-Dec-14)`. (The `vblTablename` pattern differs for different databases, and is configured in the external property file). The JOOQ generates the sql, but with the double-quote around the tablename. The query and error shown below

Query

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) COUNT FROM "vbl_default partition(p_04-Dec-14)" 
    where (rts between timestamp '2014-12-04 00:00:00.0' and timestamp '2014-12-05 00:00:00.0' and userid in (2))
```

Error

```
ORA-00972: identifier is too long
00972. 00000 -  "identifier is too long"
*Cause:    An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified.
*Action:   Specify at most 30 characters.
Error at Line: 4 Column: 29
```

Though I have set the below settings on the `DefaultDSLContext`

```
Settings settings = new Settings();
        settings.setRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.AS_IS);
```

How do I remove the quote around the table? Any other settings have I missed?

Comment: The quotes are not the problem. The table name is too long. It can have maximal 30 characters.

Comment: Yes, but that String is set in the configuration file, and I have no way to impose rule on it. And, other than that, I found `DSL.table(vblTablename)` generates query without quotes. Is that the right way to do?

Comment: I would strongly encourage not use any ( or ), and certainly no whitespaces, in the name of an object in Oracle, unless these name are forced externally.

Comment: @tvCa: That's not the problem here. It's jOOQ that renders the quotes. The OP wanted to use a plain SQL table partition clause and accidentally chose the wrong API method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind [`DSL.tableByName(String...)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#tableByName-java.lang.String...-) is that you provide a table ... by name :-)

What you're looking for is a plain SQL table, via [`DSL.table(String)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table-java.lang.String-).

You can write:

```java
// Assuming this import
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(count(VBL_DEFAULT.ID))
   .from(table("vbl_default partition(p_04-Dec-14)"))
   .where(...);
```

Or by using the convenient overload [`SelectFromStep.from(String)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SelectFromStep.html#from-java.lang.String-)

```java
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(count(VBL_DEFAULT.ID))
   .from("vbl_default partition(p_04-Dec-14)")
   .where(...);
```

More information about plain SQL in jOOQ can be obtained from this manual page:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/

#### Partition support

Note that support for Oracle partitions is on the roadmap: [#2775](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2775). If in the mean time you wish to use partitioned tables more often, you could also write your own function for that:

```java
// Beware of the risk of SQL injection, though!
public <R extends Record> Table<R> partition(Table<R> table, String partition) {
    return DSL.table("{0} partition(" + partition + ")", table);
}
```

... and then:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(count(VBL_DEFAULT.ID))
   .from(partition(VBL_DEFAULT, "p_04-Dec-14"))
   .where(...);
```